# SPSS dataset restructuring involving variable for survey completion date

Tags: spss

I'm using SPSS and have a dataset comprised of individuals' responses to a survey question.  This is longitudinal data, so the subjects have taken the survey at least twice and some as many as four or five times.

My variables are `ID` (scale), `date` of survey completion (date - dd-mmm-yyyy), and `response` to survey question (scale).

The dataset is sorted by `ID` then `date` (ascending).  Each `date` corresponds to survey time 1, time 2, etc.  What I would like to do is compute a new variable `time` that corresponds to the survey completion dates for a particular participant.  I would then like to use that variable to complete a long-to-wide restructuring of the dataset.

So, I'd like to accomplish the following and am not sure how to go about doing it:

1) I have something like this:

```
ID Date          Assessment_Answer
----------------------------------
1  01-Jan-2009   4
1  01-Jan-2010   1
1  01-Jan-2011   5
2  15-Oct-2012   6
2  15-Oct-2012   0
```

2) Want to compute another variable that would give me this:

```
ID Date          Assessment_Answer  Time
-----------------------------------------
1  01-Jan-2009   4                  Time1 
1  01-Jan-2010   1                  Time2
1  01-Jan-2011   5                  Time3   
2  15-Oct-2012   6                  Time1
2  15-Oct-2013   0                  Time2
```

3) And restructure so that I have something like this:

```
ID Time1 Time2 Time3 Time4
--------------------------
1      4     1     5
2      6     0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [sequential case processing](http://andrewpwheeler.wordpress.com/2013/02/18/using-sequential-case-processing-for-data-management-in-spss/) to create a variable that is a counter within each ID. So for example:

```
*Making fake data.
DATA LIST FREE / ID (F1.0) Date (DATE10) Assessment_Answer (F1.0).
BEGIN DATA
1 01-Jan-2009 4
1 01-Jan-2010 1
1 01-Jan-2011 5
2 15-Oct-2012 6
2 15-Oct-2012 0
END DATA.

*Making counter within ID.
SORT CASES BY Id Date.
DO IF ($casenum = 1) OR (Id <> LAG(ID)).
  COMPUTE Time = 1.
ELSE.
  COMPUTE Time = LAG(Time) + 1.
END IF.
FORMATS Time (F2.0).
EXECUTE.
```

Now you can use `CASESTOVARS` to reshape the data like you requested.

```
CASESTOVARS
  /ID = Id
  /INDEX = Time
  /DROP Date.
```